# trying to get the selected option to user object using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to get the designation variable to the user object. I tried below code , but it is not working. And I am getting same problem with adding date too.

*app.js*

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.Submit = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      };

      $scope.Reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };

      $scope.Reset();
    }]);
```

My html code

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" >Designation</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select name="designation" id="designation" ng-model="user.designation">
      <option value="Assistant General Manager">Assistant General Manager</option>
      <option value="General Manager">General Manager</option>
      <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
      <option value="Assistant Manager">Assistant Manager</option>
      //I tried to print the user object, but it is getting nothing.Here I was trying to read the value of that option.
      </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code for date

```
<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Date Of Birth(mm-dd-yy)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div  data-date="12-02-2012" class="input-append date datepicker">
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.dob"  data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" class="span11" >
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: where are you tring to print the user object?

Comment: can u create demo in fiddle or plnkr

Comment: can you put the code pertinent, I mean the printing part.

Comment: It is preferably best to use angular's "ng-options" service when you are dealing with Select element

Answer (score 0):

You have to call module name and controller name in the template. Also you have to display the 'user' object in the template to show the selected designation and entered date.

see this link
http://plnkr.co/edit/fs4qQJfosCBwDD4861sM?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" >Designation</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <select name="designation" id="designation" ng-model="user.designation">
            <option value="Assistant General Manager">Assistant General Manager</option>
            <option value="General Manager">General Manager</option>
            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="Assistant Manager">Assistant Manager</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Date Of Birth(mm-dd-yy)</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div  data-date="12-02-2012" class="input-append date datepicker">
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.dob"  data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" class="span11" >
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{user | json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```